# Rendering an infinite 2d map grid into a view which is fixed(5x5 lets say) on demand

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A map grid in a game, ex: a 5*5 view is present.

The map is huge and on drag/scroll of the grid other grid elements come into view. How would you render the view since we cannot render the whole map at once. Suppose that we have x & y cooridnates in an array.

How do we progressively render the view on drag/scroll in javascript?